# How to getText() from find_all

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, gettext

I'm completely new to programming and I'm trying to write my first program, amazon scrapper. I wonder how can I get `getText()` from find_all command. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

url = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=msi+laptop&crid=2QIX2XTRWVVU7&sprefix=msi+laptop%2Caps%2C281&ref=nb_sb_noss_1"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en",
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")


names = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class": 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal'})
names_lenght = len(names)
print(names_lenght)
for i in range(names_lenght):
    print(names[i])
```

Comment: Just so you're aware, Amazon blocks automated requests to their website. This includes scrapers. Should you print the `soup` object, you will get the error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code is correct and is locating those elements, you can do (keeping it within your code):

```
names = [...]
for name in names:
    print(name.get_text())
```

BeautifulSoup documentation: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/